# Diagnosing a dead computer

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

I built my own desktop computer about a year and a half ago and it's been working fine. Recently I went out of town for about ten days and left my surge protector turned off. When I returned, the computer would no longer turn on. No fans start up, no lights come on, no POST, no beep codes, there's no indication that anything is happening. It seems really strange that it would just stop working completely while shut off.

I have tried a lot of troubleshooting and I'm just totally stuck. Here's what I've done:

- reseated all connections and cables
- tested the PSU using [this guy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00Q8SUYHW): PSU is working
- tested CMOS battery: it is giving 3V
- unplugged all peripherals, devices and RAM, everything except for CPU and CPU fan: still nothing
- removed the power button headers on the case and manually shorted the pins to see if that cable was the problem: still nothing
- RMA'd the motherboard: still nothing
- RMA'd the CPU: still nothing

There's not even a light coming on on the motherboard to indicate that it's getting any power, but I'm not sure if the board has such a light anyway.

I am totally out of ideas. Having replaced the motherboard and CPU would seem to indicate that those aren't the problem. I wonder if perhaps the power isn't getting to the board somehow even though the PSU is working?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

---

In case it's relevant, here are the main hardware components:

- [ASRock H170M Pro4 motherboard](http://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/H170M%20Pro4/index.us.asp)
- Intel Core i5-6500 CPU
- Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (2 x 8GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM
- no discrete GPU

Comment: Make sure the "clear CMOS" jumper is not in the clear position. If possible, test with another PSU just in case there's something subtly wrong with it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  Ah, should have mentioned that. I checked the clear CMOS jumper already and it's in the correct position.

Comment: Please don't be offended as I don't think you are stupid, but just crossing out the probable: PSUs usually "suck in" a lot of electrical current when switched on/plugged in - perhaps a circuit breaker (before, not in the PSU) fell/melted?

Comment: @flolilolilo The surge protector is still working fine and is powering other devices (eg my laptop, a lamp, etc) so that's not the problem either.

Comment: How about the actual kettle lead between the PSU and the socket? These are also normally fused...

Comment: @djsmiley2k That cable also would have been tested when I tested the PSU. Or at least the little tester thing reported everything working fine when the PSU was plugged into the power strip with that cord.

Comment: Does that PSU Tester generate fake demand too? A fuse (*can*) work at a very low demand, only to fail again at higher, depending on it's composition.

Comment: I have had a PSU that seemed to generate the right voltages but would fail as soon as the load ramped up.  The symptom I saw for that was the cooling fans would all "twitch" right as the power was turned on, but no other power signs.

Comment: @djsmiley2k How would I know if it was generating fake demand? It doesn't have much in the way of a manual, unfortunately.

Comment: @techturtle Maybe that's what's going on, then. I'm not even getting a twitch, though.

Comment: You wouldn't. The wonders of cheap tools eh? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the PSU in the end. I finally got hold of a spare one to test with and it booted up fine. Stupid cheap-ass PSU tester isn't worth crap, apparently.